# write multiple files from a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, file, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3D array with shape: (766L, 256L, 256L), i need to create a file for every one of the 766 slices in the array, here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pyfits as fit

data = fit.open('lsb_0299170159_0x53c_sci.fit')
scidata=data[0].data     #Here is the data
print scidata #This is a part of the data to show the structure

>>>[[[  1.93521921e-02   5.53070288e-03   5.54129062e-03 ...,   7.59920711e-
03
 7.43154995e-03   9.53296479e-03]
[  5.75147476e-03   6.56543719e-03   6.83003664e-03 ...,   4.90503712e-03
   5.36678405e-03   3.56429932e-03]
[  4.48714197e-03   6.52663829e-03   6.36298675e-03 ...,   5.20661334e-03
   4.07732278e-03   8.60160124e-03]
..., 
[  3.72386798e-02   3.89487632e-02   3.83604541e-02 ...,   6.86576292e-02
   7.70815611e-02   8.00874010e-02]
[  3.48356217e-02   3.67552601e-02   3.45812403e-02 ...,   7.06715509e-02
   6.99861422e-02   7.58737400e-02]
[  3.13520059e-02   3.35403681e-02   3.80725004e-02 ...,              nan
              nan              nan]]

[[  1.93521921e-02   1.42930017e-03   1.38372893e-03 ...,   1.31980027e-03
    1.37834414e-03   1.39542914e-03]
 [  1.73271971e-03   1.41039363e-03   1.52022589e-03 ...,   1.29821908e-03
    1.20712281e-03   1.24027242e-03]
 [  1.73819589e-03   1.48109102e-03   1.49079110e-03 ...,   1.19586918e-03
    1.21934328e-03   1.35999266e-03]
 ..., 
 [  3.46756959e-03   3.67738772e-03   3.22443643e-03 ...,   4.02061298e-04
    6.46648754e-04   7.07142055e-04]
 [  3.69005208e-03   3.11211054e-03   3.23838764e-03 ...,   5.41916583e-04
    4.33047127e-04   5.89787844e-04]
 [  3.40519636e-03   3.49198561e-03   3.19557916e-03 ...,              nan
               nan              nan]]

for i in range(scidata.shape[0]):

    with open('leisa1{}.csv'.format(i), "wb") as outfile:

       np.savetxt(outfile,i,fmt='%.5f',delimiter=' ',footer='====')
```

But after runnig i get the next error, (i edited following the coments, the first error disappear but now this shows up):

```
ncol = X.shape[1]

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: #1. Fix your indentation. #2 What do you think the error means?

Comment: That's strange, are you sure you aren't passing `rb` or something? You shouldnt get that error. Although, it's not going to create the filename you expect. Instead, you should iterate over `for i, array in enumerate(scidata):`

Comment: nop the code is exacly as i posted, i change the line but now i have a diferent error: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: It's impossible to debug your current code without your datafile. Can you instead create a small 3d array directly in the code? This will allow us to solve your coding problem, and you can then deal with reading your file. Alternatively. post your datafile somewhere public and include a URL in the question.

Comment: Unfortunately i cant, the data comes from a fits data cube, i extracted one of its table data whit the line: scidata=data[0].data, its neccesary to upload it somewhere? i put a part of the array in the code to show its structure;  actually i was able to write all the array in a single file, but this just doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
for i in scidata:
```

The above loop will give you one of the 766 slices each time, not an index which is what you're using in creating the `.csv` file.

So, change that line to

```
for i in range(scidata.shape[0]):
    # code follows
```

Or as mentioned in the comments, use:

```
for idx, slice in enumerate(scidata):
    # code follows
```

Comment: i change the line but now i have a diferent error:    IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: @JavierSuarez what is the shape of `scidata` ?

Comment: it is (766L, 256L, 256L)